# Want to know Httpurlconnection.setConnectTimeout() working

Tags: java, http, connection

I have made connection to the wechat api using HttpUrlConnection and set connectTimeOut to 500 milis and got the response in 3 seconds and now I decreased the connectTimeOut to 100 milis and getting the response in 2 seconds. So not able to understand the reason behind this, see the code and javadoc but not found anything related to it.

Comment: You are confused. Connect timeout is not the time that will be spent to make the connection, but the limit that you want the connection is performed before that. If the connection couldn't be performed, then a Exception will be thrown

Comment: @bigdestroyer I am not confused with that statement I know that connectTimeOut is the time that for which application wait for connection to happen, if not happen then a socketexception is there, that's why very curious to know the answer of my question.

Comment: Is this result reproducable? What code did you use for validating your assumption?

Comment: @SubOptimal, yes all time reproducable

Comment: Then you should post a piece of code. Especially the piece which shows how you create/open the connection and retrieve the responce.

Answer (score 0):

You are confused. Connection timeout is not the maximum time to read the response, it is the maximum time to create the connection. Sending the request and reading the response come afterwards.

If you got a response, clearly the connection succeeded within your timeout period, but it then took some seconds to read the response. These are not the same thing.

Possibly you may want to set a read timeout as well, or instead.

But the timeouts you're setting are ridiculously short. Three seconds for a connect timeout and ten seconds for a read timeout would be about the minimum.